# How can I use fractions in Idris?

Tags: fractions, idris

When I attempt to divide one integer by another, I get the following message:

```
Idris> 6 / 8
Can't find implementation for Fractional Integer
```

What exactly does this mean? **How can I use rational numbers in Idris?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idris does not have a built-in type for rational numbers.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Idris/comments/2f9f92/does_idris_have_a_rational_type_dataratio/) The error message you are seeing means that the `(/)` function, which is a method of the [`Fractional`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/1.0/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Interfaces.html#Prelude.Interfaces.Fractional) interface, requires that its arguments be of a type that implements that interface; however, the only type that currently implements the `Fractional` interface is `Double`:

```
Idris> :doc Fractional
Interface Fractional

Parameters:
    ty

Constraints:
    Num ty

Methods:
    (/) : Fractional ty => ty -> ty -> ty

        infixl 9

        The function is Total
    recip : Fractional ty => ty -> ty


        The function is Total
Implementations:
    Fractional Double
```